# Using Amazon Systems Manager how to install AWS CLI for Linux

Tags: amazon-systems-manager

Is there a predefined script that can be used to install AWS CLI using Amazon Systems Manager?

Answer (score 0):

The closest think I can think about is AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage: https://console.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/documents/AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage/description?region=us-east-1

Alternatively, you could use the standard document and pass these 3 lines to execute:

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
```